# Problems encountered when updating DryIoc from version 4.8.8 to 5.4.1

Tags: asp.net

I have decided to update the dryioc version in my project from 4.8.8 to 5.4.1, and as a result, the `Type[] GetGenericParamsAndArgs(this Type type)` method has become unavailable. Here is an example of my code where it is used:

```
container.Register(

                typeof(IAsyncRepository<>),
                 typeof(AsyncRepository<>),

                reuse: Reuse.Scoped,

                 made: Parameters.Of.Details((request, p) =>
                     p.ParameterType
                      .GetGenericDefinitionOrNull() == typeof(IDeletingStrategy<>)
                && (!p.ParameterType
                      .GetGenericParamsAndArgs()
                      .FirstOrDefault()
                     ?.IsAssignableTo<IUndeletable>() ?? false) // ToDo check logic here

                      ? ServiceDetails.Of(value: null)
                      : null)); // the default injection behavior
```

How can I replace this method?

I couldn't find any guides for updating versions, nor did I find a method that could replace the one needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Type.GetGenericArguments()` instead.